# How to reference to previous matching record using arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting, gs-vlookup

I have a project spreadsheet, with project managers entering current progress status for each project for each month where there was some activity. So the columns A B and C are filled, I need to be able to figure out the column D using arrayformula.
(note that there was no activity/record for "Project 1" in June 2019)

I thought I would first need a helper column to find the date of the previous record for the project and then vlookup the date for the project and return the progress of that date. But I got stuck when trying to figure out the date for the previous record for the project, but I'm sort of stuck. Maybe someone here can help me with the arrayformula I should enter in D2 in order to get the values D2:D6

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DM8ZK6FwBFAmqUg5bv3o-aTIDtVKKMfGRXc2g9SSYgw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", C2:C-IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 COUNTIFS(B2:B, B2:B, ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B))&B2:B, {
 COUNTIFS(B2:B, B2:B, ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B))+1&B2:B, C2:C}, 2, 0)), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, {SORT(A2:A)&INDEX(SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 1),,2), 
 IF(A2:A<>"", INDEX(SORT(A2:C, 1, 1, 2, 1),,3)-IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 COUNTIFS(INDEX(SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 1),,2), INDEX(SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 1),,2), 
 ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B))&INDEX(SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 1),,2), {
 COUNTIFS(INDEX(SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 1),,2), INDEX(SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 1),,2), 
 ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B))+1&INDEX(SORT(A2:B, 1, 1, 2, 1),,2), 
 INDEX(SORT(A2:C, 1, 1, 2, 1),,3)}, 2, 0)), )}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dK45mmeJjc_XmgffP5OjCS43OmKmOuQpA-82x8-X6EA/copy)

---

## UPDATE 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E; {
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;1)&
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;2)&
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;3)&
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;4)&
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;5)\ IF(
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;6)<>""; 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;6)-IFNA(VLOOKUP(IF(
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;3)<>""; COUNTIFS(
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;2); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;2); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;3); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;3); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;4); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;4); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;5); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;5); ROW(K2:K); "<="&ROW(K2:K)); )&
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;2)&
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;3)&
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;4)&
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;5); {IF(
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;3)<>""; COUNTIFS(
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;2); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;2); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;3); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;3); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;4); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;4); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;5); 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;5); ROW(K2:K); "<="&ROW(K2:K))+1; )&
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;2)&
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;3)&
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;4)&
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;5)\ 
 INDEX(SORT({A2:A\B2:B\C2:C\D2:D\E2:E\F2:F}; 5; 1; 4; FALSE; 1; 1; 2; 1);;6)}; 2; 0)); )}; 2; 0)))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ox85rC7p9H6KCzVH_84cyp8hSWX6_R4-Sw5Tn-lWgiY/edit#gid=554242257)

Comment: I don't know how you do the magic, but it works! Thanx! Your formula doesn't work on non-sorted rows?
This is a sheet with non-sorted rows: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DM8ZK6FwBFAmqUg5bv3o-aTIDtVKKMfGRXc2g9SSYgw/edit#gid=578321031

Comment: Hmm, I've rearranged the rows, and it doesn't show the correct values ;(

Comment: Yes, my table is unsorted. I could use a helper sheet to sort it, but the thing is already not very responsive and I'm a bit reluctant to add new sheets. Dates do matter, I need to find out the delta between current months progress, and the progress of the last month with a record. If there is no activity then there is no record for the month, so I might have to compare July with April if no record for May and June.

Comment: I've c&p your formula in G2, but results don't seem to be correct ;(

Comment: @Mara answer updated. demo sheet included with step by step explanation

Comment: ,this breakdown was very helpful, I've extended it with few more criterions (client/type/group), but I don't understand how you did the magic to put all the red column formulas into  one single cell . This is my current draft, G2 is missing, the rest is fine. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qzAp9CjUFRm6u-w7laZjByaoHoXdFAG-g2g8ulBK9LI/edit?usp=sharing